# How to watch Windows boot process

Tags: windows-10, boot

My PC, running Windows 10 is taking a long time to reach the desktop screen. I have timed the various stages as best I can.  It previously booted so fast that there was hardly time to hit F11 when necessary.  It changed several weeks ago and as far as I can recall I had not added any hardware.

- from switch on to motherboard splash screen 30 secs
- from splash screen to appearance of small spinning circle 20 secs
  (MSI board with AMD processor)
- from the appearance of a spinning circle to the Windows Welcome screen 20 secs.
- from Welcome screen to desktop 8 secs

I recall many years ago being able to watch files/drivers etc being loaded on a console-type window so it was apparent which ones were taking a long time. I can't find any way to do this, the Windows boot log doesn't give any time info.

- My Baseboard is MSI
- Baseboard Product is A320M PRO-VH PLUS(MS-7807)
- Processor is AMD A10-9700 RADEON R7
- BIOS Mode UEFI
- BIOS version American Megatrends Inc 3.80, 16/03/2018
- SMBIOS version 2.8
- OS Windows 10 Pro
- OS version 10.0.19045 Build 19045

Any advice on how to pursue this slow start problem is appreciated.

20/02/23  FIXED
Windows Disk Manager showed a drive marked unallocated,  I tried to initialise this drive but received an error message like 'not correct function'.
Opened the case and removed cables from each drive in turn.  I have 2 SSD drives and 1 HDD.   Disconnecting the HDD resulted in a normal boot time.   How do I mark the answer that helped?

Comment: Tried MSCONFIG limit options - made no difference.

Comment: Check out the boot logging feature of the Process Monitor application from Microsoft's Sysinternals collection of utilities.

Answer (score 1):

> rom switch on to motherboard splash screen 30 secs?

But the boot or Windows aren't even starting at this moment.
I'd say it's the BIOS, a component, or the motherboard.

First, unplug all drives, eventual USB key, logitech unifying, etc - unplug everything not necessary.

Try to see if the splash screen comes FAR FAR faster (it should show within a couple of seconds maybe?)

If not, but **carefully**:

- take note of the important / very specific things in your BIOS configuration
- reset the BIOS to factory default
- measure the splash screen delay

If still not:

- consider the BIOS upgrade, yours is 2018, the latest 2022-07-15
- carefully read the whole procedure
- measure again the splash screen delay

If splash screen is coming fast, then set back your options in BIOS, retry, if still OK plug back the drives etc.

Ah, and check the RAM also using this on an USB:

https://www.memtest86.com/

*Please don't brick your system: playing with BIOS and upgrading MAY be deadly for the PC. If you don't know about it read a ton, at least, or better find someone to help you.*

Answer (score 0):

This might help you - it's not terribly "verbose", but it does add a bit more info to the screen when booting, and when shutting the computer down.

Save the contents of the below code into a .reg file, and execute it. Reboot the computer afterwards. You can also do it manually via regedit, of course.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System]
"VerboseStatus"=dword:1
;verbose startup
```

Otherwise - I would also take a look in the `Event Viewer` to see if there is any information there.

Comment: Changed the Registry, only effect was to display 'Please wait preparing windows' over the Welcome screen.  Looked at EventViewer - a number of warnings concerning WindowsSecurityCenter saying Unavailable SID.   I assume the Registry is read when the Windows OS starts up after the MSI splash screen and I am wondering what is causing the delay before then and the delay whilst the splash screen is displayed.

Comment: That, again, has nothing to do with Windows, cannot be seen, proghrammed from Windows and nothing will be logged by Windows because it happens before the Windows boot. It would happen the exact same way regardless of the OS. Many MSI boards are somewhat slow in POST and certain hatdware to be initialized can take longer.